# Como calcular el valor de Pi con base la serie de Euler para Pi medio

Tags: python, recursión

Tengo un ejercicio el cual no consigo resolver, adjunto el enunciado de la pregunta:

> 1. Construya un programa que calcule el valor de Pi con base la serie de Euler para
>    Pi medio.
>
> -Nombre de la función pi_euler(Error). Argumentos: entrada Error: valor de
> error en punto flotante; Las salidas: el valor de n correspondiente al término
> de la sumatoria para cumplir con el error y un número con el valor de Pi. Los
> valores de error deben ser menores que 1.

El ejemplo de resultado proporcionado con el ejercicio es el siguiente:

[image: Serie de euler]

Realmente he intentado de muchas maneras pero no consigo el resultado tal como se muestra en el ejemplo.

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
def pi_euler(error):
    if isinstance(error,float) and 0<error<1:
        return pi_euler_aux(error, 0, 1)
    else:
        return "debe ser un numero flotante mayor que 0 y menor que 1"

def pi_euler_aux(error,n,res):
    if 0.5<error<1:
        return (0,1)
    else:
        a = (2**n*facto(n)**2)/facto(2*n+1)
        res = a
        if res<error:
            return (n-1,res)
        else:
            return pi_euler_aux(error,n+1,res)
```

Pero esta mal ya que en un inicio había entendido otra cosa, había entendido que el resultado tenia que ser menor que el valor de error. un poco torpe de mi parte pero así me lo explicaron y me quede con esa idea, luego me percate que no tenia sentido en base al ejemplo y ahí me percate que el ejemplo esta bien... Bueno, agradeceré cualquier contribución o retroalimentación.

> **NOTA:** Algo importante es que no puedo hacer uso de funciones preconstruidas como para obtener el factorial por lo que la función `fact()` que se encuentra en la formula es para obtener el factorial, no la incluí aquí ya que no lo considero necesario. Además solo puedo usar recursividad de cola o simple no puedo usar iteraciones ni recursividad de pila...

Comment: ¿Cómo calculas el error? Porque `res=a` significa `res=pi/2`

Comment: @CandidMoe eso es lo que no acabo de comprender, como clcular el error, y como verificar que se cumpla ese error, como dije ese codigo esta mal porque era de lo que estaba haciendo anteriormente, pero no se como cambiarlo para hacerlo de la forma que solicitan...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estabas bastante cerca. El error es el propio término `a` que acabas de calcular. Es decir, para aproximar el valor de pi (bueno, en realidad pi/2 según la fórmula de Euler), lo que haces es ir añadiendo términos, cada vez más pequeñitos, cada uno de los cuales se calcula con la fórmula de los factoriales. Cuando al aplicar la fórmula el término que te saldría es menor que el error que se admite, ese término ya no hace falta, se descarta y se puede salir. El valor aproximado de pi/2 será la suma de todos los términos computados hasta ese momento.

Implementar esto de forma iterativa (con un bucle) sería sencillo. Voy a hacerlo primero así para que se entienda mejor, y luego lo pasamos a forma recursiva.

Primero, pondré en fórmula aparte la función que calcula el término n-ésimo:

```
def termino(n):
  return (2**n*facto(n)**2)/facto(2*n+1)
```

Ahora, como dije, se trata de ir llamando a esta función e ir sumando lo que devuelve, deteniéndose cuando el valor del término sea menor que el error:

```
def pi_euler_iterativa(error):
  n = 0
  resultado = 0
  while True:
     a = termino(n)
     if a < error:
        break
     resultado += a
     n += 1
  return (n-1, resultado)
```

Puedes comprobar que pasa los test del ejercicio.

### Versión recursiva

En la versión recursiva (con recursión de cola) el incremento de `n` y el ir añadiendo `a` al resultado se debe hacer en el momento de pasar los parámetros a la llamada recursiva. Por tanto quedaría así:

```
def pi_euler_aux(error, n, resultado):
    a = termino(n)
    if a < error:
        return (n-1, resultado)
    else:
        return pi_euler_aux(error, n+1, resultado+a)
```

Y la inicialización de `n` y de `resultado` que la versión iterativa hacía antes del bucle, en este caso se hace al invocar por primera vez `pi_euler_aux()`, que se invocaría por tanto así:

```
def pi_euler(error):
    if isinstance(error,float) and 0<error<1:
        return pi_euler_aux(error, 0, 0)
    else:
        return "debe ser un numero flotante mayor que 0 y menor que 1"
```

### NOTA:

Está bien que te enseñen implementaciones recursivas, y en particular la recursividad de cola es importante en muchos lenguajes porque es un tipo de recursividad que el compilador o el intérprete pueden optimizar. Esta optimizción consiste en que, en vez de llamar a la función, se sobreescriben los parámetros y se salta de nuevo al inicio de la función, evitando así consumir marcos de pila. En el fondo el optimizador está haciendo de forma encubierta un "goto", que en el fondo implementa el bucle de la versión iterativa.

Sin este tipo de optimización una la recursividad está limitada por el tamaño de la pila, y cuando lleves un cierto número de llamadas anidadas se producirá un error de desbordamiento de pila. Por desgracia esta optimización sólo puede hacerse si la recursividad es de tipo cola (pues el retorno de la llamada anidada no necesita hacerse a la función que la llamó recursivamente, porque esta función no usa su resultado salvo para retornarlo).

Lo que es peor: **python no hace esta optimización** (decisión de su creador), por lo que tanto da que la recursividad sea o no de tipo cola, Python siempre hace una llamada "normal" (sin trucos de goto) y por tanto estarás limitado siempre por el tamaño de la pila.

Por ello, fuera de ser un ejercicio académico, la implementación recursiva dada en esta solución no es práctica. Es preferible la versión iterativa con bucle.

Comment: Listo ya entiendo, muchas gracias y gracias ademas por los consejos

Answer (score 1):

La solución es puramente iterativa. La ecuación planteada nos dice la forma de calcular la sumatoria sin recurrir directamente a factoriales ni recursividad.

Para calcular Euler calculamos cada termino de la sumatoria en base a la anterior, lo que solo requiere una multiplicación y una división:

```
termino_0 = 1 / 1
termino_1 = termino_0 * 1 / 3
termino_2 = termino_1 * 2 / 5
etc.
```

Tras calcular el nuevo término, se compara contra el error. Si el término es menor, se retorna de la función.

```
def euler(error):
    suma = 0
    denom = 0
    divid = 1
    termino = 1
    pasos = 0
    while termino > error:
        suma += termino
        denom += 1
        divid += 2
        termino *= denom / divid
        pasos += 1

    return pasos, suma
```

**Demo**

```
for er in [0.5707, .2374, 0.1041]:
    pasos, pi = euler(er)
    print(pasos, pi)
```

produce:

```
1 1
2 1.3333333333333333
3 1.4666666666666666
```